# How can I get this line from a big file in shell

Tags: shell

I have a big file, in which there are blocks like the following:

```
....
Org Id VIN                  Plate Registration   Error Code
------ -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------------
124    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    WI-V-456             Info 1
124    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb    DH-BE-1111           Info 2
124    ccccccccccccccccc    A-RM-1332            Info 3
124    ddddddddddddddddd    S-SH-3333            Info 4
124    eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    RH-L-360             Info 5

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
....
```

I just want to extract the column `Error Code` of each, how can I do it?

```
cat ${fichier} | while read line
   do
   if [ "x${line}" = 'xOrg Id VIN                  Plate Registration   Error Code' ]
        then 
            echo  ${line}
                        ##
        fi
   done
```

Comment: Do all desired lines have the format `Info XXX`?

Comment: If the format of the values in the `Error Code` column is distinct (e.g. it will always be "Info 1" and/or "Warn 4" and/or "Error 255") you might also use `sed` to pick it out: `sed -r 's/(<APPROPRIATE REGEX HERE>)$/\1/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use `awk`:

```
$ awk '$NF>0{print $(NF-1), $NF}' file
Error Code
Info 1
Info 2
Info 3
Info 4
Info 5
```

This will print the penultimate and last fields, in case last one is something like text or numbers.

Comment: This is only reliable if the columns always have values with no spaces and if the column count does not change. (Awk by default splits fields (columns) by whitespace chars.)

Comment: Yes you are right, I posted the answer based on the current sample input / desired output. If it happens to be different I will edit accordingly. Already asked the OP to see if it is like this or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. @fedorqui has shown one of them using awk, you can also use mixing `cut` with `grep`:

```
$ cut -c 50- testfile.txt | grep ^[^-]
Error Code
Info 1
Info 2
Info 3
Info 4
Info 5
```

which means: cut testfiletxt- show characters from 50 to the end of line (`-c 50-`), an then send it to `grep` to show only lines which don't start with "-" char.